# Sort values intra group

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': [2, 13, 24, 15, 11, 44], 
    'category': ["shirts", "pants", "shirts", "tops", "hat", "tops"],
})
```

```
    price   category
0       2     shirts
1      13      pants
2      24     shirts
3      15       tops
4      11        hat
5      44       tops
```

I want to sort values in such a way that:

- Find what is the highest price of each category.
- Sort categories according to highest price (in this case, in descending order: tops, shirts, pants, hat).
- Sort each category according to higher price.

The final dataframe would look like:

```
    price   category
0      44       tops
1      15       tops
2      24     shirts
3      24     shirts
4      13      pants
5      11        hat
```

Comment: A good pandas MRE is a rare sight these days. +1 for a simple, minimal dataframe code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of one-liners, so here's my solution:

```py
# Add column with max-price for each category
df = df.merge(df.groupby('category')['price'].max().rename('max_cat_price'),
              left_on='category', right_index=True)

# Sort
df.sort_values(['category','price','max_cat_price'], ascending=False)

# Drop column that has max-price for each category
df.drop('max_cat_price', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)

   price category
5     44     tops
3     15     tops
2     24   shirts
0      2   shirts
1     13    pants
4     11      hat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```py
df.join(df.groupby("category").agg("max"), on="category", rsuffix="_r").sort_values(
    ["price_r", "price"], ascending=False
)
```

**Output**

```
   price category  price_r
5     44     tops       44
3     15     tops       44
2     24   shirts       24
0      2   shirts       24
1     13    pants       13
4     11      hat       11
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the get_group in an dataframe apply to get the max price for a category

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
'price': [2, 13, 24, 15, 11, 44], 
'category': ["shirts", "pants", "shirts", "tops", "hat", "tops"],
 })
 grouped=df.groupby('category')

 df['price_r']=df['category'].apply(lambda row: grouped.get_group(row).price.max())
 df=df.sort_values(['category','price','price_r'], ascending=False)
 print(df)
```

output

```
    price category  price_r
 5     44     tops       44
 3     15     tops       44
 2     24   shirts       24
 0      2   shirts       24
 1     13    pants       13
 4     11      hat       11
```